# React - selenium tests

Tags: javascript, selenium, reactjs

**Solved, see answer below**

I test a React app with selenium.

I need to change the value of an input field, which is linked to the state of the object. In short (relevant parts of the code), a change in this input allows it's value to be submited only if it is not empty:

```
# react object

render: function(){

    <input ... onChange={this.handleTextChange} className="myInput" />

    <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Submit</button> 
},

handleTextChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({text: e.target.value});
},

handleSubmit: function() {
    if(this.state.text.length > 0) {
    // relevant code that is never executed
    // because although we change the value of the input, the state does not update 
    }
},
```

The code works but I cannot find a way to test it because I cannot find any js manipulation which would update the input AND reflect in the state of the object.
I tried the following solutions

```
# value update
self.selenium.execute_script("var input = document.querySelectorAll('input.myInput')[0]; form.value = 'New message!'");
```

The word 'New message!' actually appears in the input but does not update the state of the object.
I then tried focusing on the input and triggering a keyup event, without success

```
# try focus and keyUp
# source https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/simulate-javascript-key-events
self.selenium.execute_script("""
var form = document.querySelectorAll("input.messageFormInput")[0]; 
form.focus();
var keyboardEvent = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
var initMethod = typeof keyboardEvent.initKeyboardEvent !== 'undefined' ? "initKeyboardEvent" : "initKeyEvent";
keyboardEvent[initMethod](
               "keydown", // event type : keydown, keyup, keypress
                true, // bubbles
                true, // cancelable
                window, // viewArg: should be window
                false, // ctrlKeyArg
                false, // altKeyArg
                false, // shiftKeyArg
                false, // metaKeyArg
                40, // keyCodeArg : unsigned long the virtual key code, else 0
                0 // charCodeArgs : unsigned long the Unicode character associated with the depressed key, else 0
);
document.dispatchEvent(keyboardEvent);
""")
```

I tried the same solution with jQuery as explained here ([Is it possible to simulate key press events programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/simulate-javascript-key-events)), but it does not work either.

Any idea is very welcome. Thanks!

Comment: I'm just curious, if you're using selenium, why not just interact with the page as a normal user would, instead of firing event's manually.  For instance, why not simulate the user's behavior which fires the events based upon the interaction with the dom elements?

Comment: Hi Chris! I tried self.selenium.find_elements_by_class_name("MyInput")[0].click() . The problem is I do not knwo how to actually write text in the input.

Answer (score 1):

My bad, I was not aware of

```
self.selenium.find_elements_by_class_name('myClass')[0].send_keys("hello")
```

Which actually solves the issue. Thanks to Chris Hawkes for sending me in the right direction.

Comment: This solution saved my day. Thanks for posting!!

Comment: Glad it helps !